# Ошибка инициализации переменной и условия (Java)

Tags: java, вывод, условия, инициализация

Прошу меня простить за возможную тупость, только недавно начал учить Java. Пытался искать решение в интернете, но тщетно. Пробовал присвоить значения 0 переменным, но в итоге выдает сумму тоже 0, так что этот вариант не подходит. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли заставить эту программу работать правильно?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int c = num1 + num2; // ошибка здесь

        System.out.print("Input first number: ");

        if (a.hasNextInt())
            num1 = a.nextInt();
        else
            System.out.println("This in not number, please restart your program.");

        System.out.print("Input second number: ");

        if (b.hasNextInt())
            num2 = b.nextInt();
        else
            System.out.println("This in not number, please restart your program.");

        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Локальные переменные не имеют значений по умолчанию.
2. Обращение к локальным переменным должно быть выполнено только после того, как они будут инициализированы. т.е. объявив  `int num1;` и если не присвоить ей значение, и попытаться совершить какие-либо действия получим ошибку.       `int c = num1 + num2; // ошибка здесь`
   надо сразу инициализировать переменные нулями

   ```
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
   ```

следовательно чтобы всё заработало надо выражение

```
 int c = num1 + num2; // ошибка здесь
```

переместить "вниз" программы, перед `System.out.println(c);`, чтобы сложение происходило после считывания и присваивания с клавиатуры.

Comment: попробовал, но это не дает результата, все равно та же ошибка, компилятор похоже не совсем понимает что мне от него нужно.

Comment: я изначально писал System.out.println(num1+num2) и тоже выдавало ошибку.

Comment: а что за ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: "The local variable num1 may not have been initialized
 The local variable num2 may not have been initialized"

Comment: попробуй их сразу инициализировать нулями. сейчас ответ поправлю

Comment: спасибо огромное! Помогло!

Comment: пожалуйста, удачи в начинаниях.